# Why a program starts and exits right away?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, webdev.webserver

This is kind of weird. Sometimes when I start my ASP.NET page in Visual Studio 2010 in debug mode, I can see IE starting, data initializing, controls loading and there is stuff in the output log.

But then sometimes IE just exits, and at the end of the output log, it says:

> The program '[2788] WebDev.WebServer40.EXE: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -1073741816 (0xc0000008).

I wonder, do I have something wrong in my code? It just happens sometimes. I was wondering if same thing will happen if I publish on IIS7 for actual operation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't sound like anything is wrong. It may have more to do with the debugger than your code. Otherwise, just blame IE. It's a good scapegoat.

Comment: [This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbide/thread/8c37a193-5c56-46c4-a333-3a81cf103274/) may help out.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out when I got home... For some reason my I can't go to any microsoft page in my office network.. well only my computer, weird...

Answer (score 0):

I had this once and shortening the name of my project worked like charm.